# Making a bot that can add multiple roles to a user at once

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

Basically I'm using nextcord, a fork of discord.py. I'm kind of new to programming in general, but since I like or have been on discord for some time and want to pursue a career requiring programming I said doing a small project such as this would be a good start.

```
import asyncio
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord.ext.commands import guild_only

@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def giverole(ctx, member : nextcord.Member, role : nextcord.Role):
    if role in member.roles:
        await member.add_roles(role, atomic = True)
        embed8a = nextcord.Embed(description = f"Removed **{role}** from **{member}**", color = nextcord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.send(embed = embed8a)
    else: 
        await member.add_roles(role, atomic = True)
        embed7a = nextcord.Embed(description = f"Added **{role}** to **{member}**", color = nextcord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.send(embed = embed7a)

Anyways, my issue is that in the code below I am able to add one role to a user at a time, however not multiple. According to the nextcord/discord.py documentation, using the "Atomic = true" attribute should make this possible but I've gotten several errors. I've listed the most current one below.
```

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\De'shon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1381, in invoke await ctx.command.invoke(ctx) File "C:\Users\De'shon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 948, in invoke await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs) File "C:\Users\De'shon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 174, in wrapped raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is caused by the fact that you're passing a tuple of roles to `member.add_roles()` instead of a single role.

To fix this, you can change the role parameter to accept multiple roles by using `commands.Greedy` which will allow you to pass in multiple role names separated by spaces.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def giverole(ctx, member: nextcord.Member, *roles: commands.Greedy[nextcord.Role]):
    added_roles = []
    removed_roles = []
    for role in roles:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role, atomic=True)
            removed_roles.append(role)
        else:
            await member.add_roles(role, atomic=True)
            added_roles.append(role)
    if added_roles:
        embed7a = nextcord.Embed(description=f"Added {', '.join(role.mention for role in added_roles)} to {member.mention}", color=nextcord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed7a)
    if removed_roles:
        embed8a = nextcord.Embed(description=f"Removed {', '.join(role.mention for role in removed_roles)} from {member.mention}", color=nextcord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed8a)
```